# How to use controller method from view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Problem : I cannot seem to call controller method from view.
Why : because i want to pass argument in the method and loop the data

In view :

```
foreach($data as $key => $val){
   foreach($methodData($val['dataID']) as $mKey => $mVal){
       echo $mVal['name'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not recomended in the MVC pattern. You should only display the data in the view (data you passed from the controller).

Think about so set up the data as you need it in your controller and pass the right model to your view.

Comment: so, what must i do to loop the data? Will i create new method in controller and parse from that method?

Comment: well, i'll just loop and create xml/array in the controller and read the data in view. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your loop should be in the model not the controller, Your model should return prepared data to the controller & controller should ONLY pass these data to a view.

Answer (score 0):

lets say there is a model called 'jungle'. in the model we search for elephants using a search term. if no elephants come back, we load a search form and pass the search term back to it.

in your controller

```
  // check first if no results came back from the model
  if( ! $data['elephants'] = $this->jungle->getElephants($searchterm) ){

     $data['searchterm'] = $searchterm ; 

     $this->load->view( 'searchform_elephants', $data ); } 

     // we have results, $elephants data structure is assigned to $data 
     // and passed to the view so it can be accessed on the view page
     else { $this->load->view( 'show_elephants', $data ); }
```

if some elephants came back, then that $elephant object (or array) is assigned to $data, and then it gets passed to the view.

so then in your view - you can foreach through the results depending on the type of data structure.

```
 foreach($elephants as $index => $elephant) : 

    echo $elephant->firstname . ' ' . $elephant->lastname ;
```

Last - if you know that what you are retrieving from the database etc is a single record - then you can assign the query results to row() . THEN in the view you don't have to do a foreach etc. For example if you are getting a unique snowflake by $id

```
    // controller 
    $data['snowflake'] = $this->blizzard->getFlakeBy($id) ; 

   // view 
   echo $snowflake->firstname ;
```

this page for the deets: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html